# Spring boot REST service stops after some time

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

After triggering the spring boot REST service, the service runs OK for hours with all requests working without any issues. What happens is that randomly after some time, it stops. When looking into the logs I find no errors, except information that the application has been destroyed.

Logs after some time

```
2016-03-09 17:07:33.488  INFO 28359 --- [Thread-12] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5df2d54c: startup date [Wed Mar 09 10:45:18 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-03-09 17:07:33.490  INFO 28359 --- [Thread-12] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2016-03-09 17:07:33.495  INFO 28359 --- [Thread-12] o.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector   : Stopped ServerConnector@585ebc93{SSL-HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8443}
2016-03-09 17:07:33.496  INFO 28359 --- [Thread-12] application                              : Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-03-09 17:07:33.496  INFO 28359 --- [Thread-12] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Stopped o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@3d3969ea{/,file:/tmp/jetty-docbase.5267015092605924805.8443/,UNAVAILABLE}
```

Maven dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.drill.exec</groupId>
            <artifactId>drill-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- used to update stopwatch -->
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.drill</groupId>
            <artifactId>drill-common</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

Any ideas to why the spring boot REST API might stop? My maven dependencies are according to the demos - and it's successfully being run - it's why the service stops after random time that doesn't make sense.

The logging settings I am using for spring boot is

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web = DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate = ERROR
logging.file = /home/REST/Logging.log
```

Comment: is there a session with expiration time ?

Comment: No, but if that's the case I would find hibernate errors in the logs.

Comment: Increase the loglevel and check what is causing the shutdown. Since it is shutting down cleanly I suspect something like a shutdown request to the embedded servlet container or spring container.

Comment: Logging is logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR - it should show me all debugging logs

Comment: Does it stop at the same time of day every time?

Comment: @PatrickGrimard nope it's really erratic. Settings for logging are as specified in my question. Those should have all details of errors/stopping of applications right?

Comment: You would think...  How are you running your Spring Boot application?

Comment: @PatrickGrimard With the normal java -jar command.

Comment: My guess FWIW is a library calling `System.exit()`. Try an app with just Spring (no hadoop etc.) to see if it suffers the same fate.

Comment: I've the same problem. I've 2 different webservices running on same server. I've kept both the jars in a different folder. but one of the services stops after running smoothly for 2-3 days. No error logs are there.

Comment: were you able to figure out the root cause?

Comment: Yes posted an answer @Sayantan

Answer (score 1):

Root cause was my staling connection to MySQL

```
spring.xxx.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.xxx.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

More details here https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/pooling.html

Comment: Hey Mez, I am facing same problem, can you let me know how do you solve this. May I need to delete the lines from application.properties mentioned above. Please share your knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mez thanks... :) I tried an opposite approach by [disabling datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387265/disable-all-database-related-auto-configuration-in-spring-boot) just for testing. Its working fine now.