# Disable Spring Data JPA and Database stuff

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So I got an application that sometimes needs a Database connection. Its a multi module project so the application depends on a jpa project. Which has a configuration:

```
/** Configuration for data source. */
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("db")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "my.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Profile({"!nodb"})
```

so this config should only be loaded if the profile "nodb" is NOT active.

Now we got the main application with this (Its more for testing right now I want a conditional class which enables/disables JPA and Database):

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
  DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
  JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class, JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.components")
```

I also tried to replace @SpringApplication like suggested here: [Disable all Database related auto configuration in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387265/disable-all-database-related-auto-configuration-in-spring-boot)

And on startup I see the following:

```
2016-12-08 10:24:44,269 - INFO  - org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version - <clinit>(30) | HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
2016-12-08 10:24:46,604 - INFO  - org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - multipleStoresDetected(170) | Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2016-12-08 10:24:46,708 - INFO  - org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - multipleStoresDetected(170) | Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2016-12-08 10:24:47,000 - INFO  - org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - multipleStoresDetected(170) | Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
```

Because I also have elasticsearch repositories. I expect that messages when JPA is activated. but not when its deactivated? The application then fails with the following:

```
2016-12-08 10:24:49,150 - [main] DEBUG - org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - report(38) | Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "default,nodb" are currently active).
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:245) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
```

The Report:

```
=========================
AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
=========================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   AopAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy', 'org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect', 'org.aspectj.lang.reflect.Advice' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.auto=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration.JdkDynamicAutoProxyConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration#dataSourceInitializer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceConfiguration matched:
      - AnyNestedCondition 1 matched 1 did not; NestedCondition on DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition.PooledDataSourceAvailable PooledDataSource found supported DataSource; NestedCondition on DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition.ExplicitType @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type) did not find property 'type' (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource,javax.sql.XADataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceConfiguration.Tomcat matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.TomcatDataSourcePoolMetadataProviderConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate', 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.TransactionManagementConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) found StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DispatcherServletConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'javax.servlet.ServletRegistration' (OnClassCondition)
      - Default DispatcherServlet did not find dispatcher servlet beans (DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DefaultDispatcherServletCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'javax.servlet.ServletRegistration' (OnClassCondition)
      - DispatcherServlet Registration did not find servlet registration bean (DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DispatcherServletRegistrationCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration#dispatcherServletRegistration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (names: dispatcherServlet; types: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet; SearchStrategy: all) found beans 'dispatcherServlet', 'dispatcherServlet' (OnBeanCondition)

   ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.elasticsearch.client.Client', 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.TransportClientFactoryBean', 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.NodeClientFactoryBean' (OnClassCondition)

   ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration#elasticsearchClient matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.elasticsearch.client.Client; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.elasticsearch.client.Client', 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration#elasticsearchConverter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.ElasticsearchConverter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration#elasticsearchTemplate matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration#mappingContext matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) found StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedTomcat matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.servlet.Servlet', 'org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.servlet.Servlet', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) found StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration#basicErrorController matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration#conventionErrorViewResolver matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'dispatcherServlet'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DefaultErrorViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration#errorAttributes matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorAttributes; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (server.error.whitelabel.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - ErrorTemplate Missing did not find error template view (ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.ErrorTemplateMissingCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration#beanNameViewResolver matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration#defaultErrorView matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: error; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   GenericCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.GenericCacheConfiguration automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

   GuavaCacheConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder', 'org.springframework.cache.guava.GuavaCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.GuavaCacheConfiguration automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

   HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean', 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement', 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' (OnClassCondition)
      - HibernateEntityManager found class 'org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManager' (HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.HibernateEntityManagerCondition)

   HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) found StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.http.encoding.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration#characterEncodingFilter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter' (OnClassCondition)

   HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration#messageConverters matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter' (OnClassCondition)

   HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration#stringHttpMessageConverter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper', 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper', 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration#jacksonObjectMapperBuilder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper', 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=jackson) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'base64ObjectMapper' (OnBeanCondition)

   JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration#mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration#jdbcTemplate matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration#namedParameterJdbcTemplate matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms' (OnClassCondition)

   JmxAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.jmx.enabled=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   JmxAutoConfiguration#mbeanExporter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JmxAutoConfiguration#mbeanServer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.management.MBeanServer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JmxAutoConfiguration#objectNamingStrategy matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jmx.export.naming.ObjectNamingStrategy; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#entityManagerFactory matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean,javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#entityManagerFactoryBuilder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#jpaVendorAdapter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#transactionManager matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration.JpaWebConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) found StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.jpa.open-in-view=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'dataSource'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean,org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JtaAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'javax.transaction.Transaction' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.jta.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   MailSenderAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage', 'javax.activation.MimeType' (OnClassCondition)
      - AnyNestedCondition 1 matched 1 did not; NestedCondition on MailSenderAutoConfiguration.MailSenderCondition.JndiNameProperty @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mail.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'; NestedCondition on MailSenderAutoConfiguration.MailSenderCondition.HostProperty @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mail.host) matched (MailSenderAutoConfiguration.MailSenderCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.mail.MailSender; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   MultipartAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.servlet.Servlet', 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver', 'javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.http.multipart.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   MultipartAutoConfiguration#multipartConfigElement matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   MultipartAutoConfiguration#multipartResolver matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   NoOpCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.NoOpCacheConfiguration automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

   PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' (OnClassCondition)

   PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration#persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.dao.exceptiontranslation.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) found StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration#serverProperties matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   SimpleCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.SimpleCacheConfiguration automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

   SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.application.admin.enabled=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration#springApplicationAdminRegistrar matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.admin.SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) found StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate', 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'transactionManager' (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration#transactionTemplate matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   VelocityAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine', 'org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   VelocityAutoConfiguration.VelocityWebConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'javax.servlet.Servlet' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) found StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   VelocityAutoConfiguration.VelocityWebConfiguration#velocityConfigurer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfig; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   VelocityAutoConfiguration.VelocityWebConfiguration#velocityViewResolver matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.velocity.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: velocityViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebClientAutoConfiguration.RestTemplateConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   WebClientAutoConfiguration.RestTemplateConfiguration#restTemplateBuilder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.servlet.Servlet', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) found StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration#hiddenHttpMethodFilter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration#httpPutFormContentFilter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mvc.formcontent.putfilter.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#defaultViewResolver matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#requestContextFilter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener,org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#viewResolver matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found beans 'beanNameViewResolver', 'defaultViewResolver', 'mvcViewResolver'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: viewResolver; types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.FaviconConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mvc.favicon.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   WebSocketAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.servlet.Servlet', 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) found StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   WebSocketAutoConfiguration.TomcatWebSocketConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat', 'org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketAutoConfiguration.TomcatWebSocketConfiguration#websocketContainerCustomizer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnJava (1.7 or newer) found 1.8 (OnJavaCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: websocketContainerCustomizer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------
    <-- CUT -->

Exclusions:
-----------
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebClientAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: The question is where the exception comes from when jpa should be deactivated. But it isn't it tires to open a connection to a database to instantiate repositories which also should be deactivated.