# Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource + Springboot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm creating a Springboot application but will be using a external MongoDB over REST. My application properties file is very simple:

**application.properties**

```
# Server
server.port=8081
```

My **global application** file is also very simple. I make a connection to my externally hosted database with a Parse initialization method:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test", "it.ozimov.springboot"})
public class TmtApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TmtApplication.class, args);

        // Database connection
        Parse.initialize("applicationId","restAPIKey", "https://parseapi.back4app.com");

    }
}
```

Why am I getting the following exception?

**Exceptions:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:42)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 48 more
```

What don't I understand about Springboot? Is it looking for some kind of database initialization because it's running on Hibernate/Tomcat?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Exclude Datasource if you don't use database.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

[you see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387265/disable-all-database-related-auto-configuration-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, having `@SpringBootApplication` and then `@EnableAutoConfiguration` didn't work for me.

What worked for me is:

```
@SpringBootApplication (exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@DependsOn("appConfig")
public class SerializationManager {
}
```

Using `@SpringBootApplication` is the same as having `@Configuration` `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` separately.