# Maven build fails if mongodb server is not present with spring boot 2?

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I am learning java and Spring boot 2

So my problem is:

```
2018-07-09 11:40:24.816  INFO 20196 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.6.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open (InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.6.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run (DefaultServerMonitor.java:114) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.6.4.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171] Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize (SocketStreamHelper.java:59) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.6.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:57) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.6.4.jar:na]
... 3 common frames omitted

2018-07-09 11:40:25.164  INFO 20196 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster: Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
```

So when Spring Boot 2 is Maven build app it stuck because of absent MongoDB server and trying to connect 3 time with timeout 30000ms, then stuck...

So I want to init this connection, after finishing of Maven build, from runtime with external config parameter, and then with @shedules monitoring check if MongoDB alive, and reconnect if it lost.

What I found for SQL is excluding autoconfiguration from [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387265/disable-all-database-related-auto-configuration-in-spring-boot) but I dont know which file is configure MongoDB from this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#auto-configuration-classes). And may be I must configure it like a @PostConstruct @bean conf files? (please suggest me example if it present and possibility to do this opportunity)

Thank you in advance!

for now I take an example of db routers:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = 
{org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration.class
,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo 
.MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {
```

exclude 2 files from autoconfigure, wrote some class for setup my properties, but I still do not know how to delay an effort of connection!

Comment: Rather than over-engineer a solution why not just add a profile that enables/disables the mongo autoconfiguration. Have it active when mongo is present?

Comment: Formatted the Java stack section and a couple typos.

Comment: may be you are right and i try to research in your way.

Comment: I tried this kind of way, but there is another problem mongorepository want to create bean independently of app had connection or not. And then crush all app cause of nested exception of connection exception to mongo db

Answer (score 2):

Skip the junit test while building the project.

Use `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` to skip the tests

or

in eclipse->Project->Run As->run configuration->Maven build-> check Skip Tests

Comment: I know why my build is stuck , I wrote this below exception. My purpose to ignore it anr build my app and after in runtime check with utility class if my mongo db is alive.

Comment: i think you are running Junit which tries to connect Mongo DB while creating build. Skip the tests while build. Updated answer

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. Should be assigned as the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

since you are using spring boot it should take care of the required versions or did you added the entries for the driver in the pom yourself.

1. try maven clean ,and force update of snapshots.
2. mongo-java-driver-3.6.4.jar either it is not compatible or not picked by the ide you are using. check the table [mongo-db-compatibilty](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#java-driver-compatibility)

Comment: I know why my build is stuck , I wrote this below exception. My purpose to ignore it anr build my app and after in runtime check with utility class if my mongo db is alive.