# Disable autowire of some of jobs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have one job in my Spring Batch that doesn't use one of the data sources (Oracle Database). However, because I'm using autowire and autoconfigure in Spring Configuration files; that job also made a connection to Oracle when it starts.

I reduce the pool-size to 1 because the data source will not be used. But, I really need to remove that connection also, meaning that I don't want to even have one Inactive and not used connection.

Any idea of how to solve that in Spring Batch?

Comment: Don't use the Spring managed datasource.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Good to refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387265/disable-all-database-related-auto-configuration-in-spring-boot

Comment: Most of the discussion @MebinJoe is a solution at the application level. However, I can't `exclude` some of the configs because other jobs in my application use the oracle database.