# Spring Boot app not connecting to the database specified in application.property for Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have developer Application in Spring boot and exported the war file and placed it in tomcat 9 server. When I try to test the API in Rest client the app is connecting to test DB instead of the DB which I declared in application.property for mongodb, below is my application.property

```
Database name.
spring.data.mongodb.database=IndianFarms

Mongo server host.
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost

Mongo server port.
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017

logging
logging.level.org.springframework.data=debug
logging.level.=error

spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_NULL
```

Can any one help me in this.

Comment: And where is the configuration of test DB is mentioned in the application?

Comment: hi @suru , can u please share any exceptions that you are getting on start up?

Comment: @Smile i have not configured test DB.

Comment: Ok, so what exactly is the test DB? How do you know the application is connecting to a particular test DB?

Comment: @Smile when i try to save some data in collection mondoDB is automatically creating test DB and saving the data in that.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387265/disable-all-database-related-auto-configuration-in-spring-boot?

Comment: @ Mandar Dharurkar I have checked the logs there is no exception every thing looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of search and research in came to know that spring boot auto configure lot of things internally. Declaration in application.properties file is not working.
We have to programmatically do this. Below is how I did it. Now Spring boot is connection to correct database which is in my case IndianFarms. @Smile thanks your suggestion helped me to find out exact cause.

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {


    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() {

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1:27017");

        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, "IndianFarms" );
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }
}
```

Comment: Gee it sure would be swell if you could add the imports namespaces for the type references...