# Springboot gives obscure errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm fiddling with Springboot but each step forward brings me two steps back it seems.

I wired my simple app together with Springboot but I'm not getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException
```

As well as this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration due to org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
```

I don't use any database. The app is very simple. Here is the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Helloer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Helloer.class, args);
        A a = ctx.getBean(A.class);
        a.speak();
    }
}
```

Here are the other two classes `A` and `B`:

```
@Component
public class A {
    @Autowired
    private B b;

    @Value("Covid 19")
    private String calamity;

    public void speak() {
        b.writeToScreen(this.calamity);
    }
}

@Component
public class B {

    public void writeToScreen(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

And here is the config:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

That's it. Simple as it can possibly be.

Here is the file structure as well as the build.gradle file content:

[image]

can someone please help me get this tiny program running by pointing me in the right direction as to the fix for this issue?

Thank you kindly in advance.

Comment: that's exactly it. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Michael, thanks kindly. Make your comment into an answer, I'll flag it as the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is related to this error message:

> This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake).

If I correctly see from your screenshot the `Helloer.java` is in the default package of your project. You need to move it into `ca.company` package. Also as you already define the `B` class as component you don't need to configure another `B` bean in the `Config` class.

Comment: Sorry, the screenshot does not show default package. They are in one called `ca.company`

Comment: Well, I am just guessing as the OP also didn't show it in the code. But I am able to run the code above simply by moving this `Helloer` class out from default package, in this case into the package `ca.company`.

Comment: There is a screenshot. You don't have to guess. It's not in the default package.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require the database autoconfiguration, you can explicitly opt-out of it.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

See also [Disable all Database related auto configuration in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387265/disable-all-database-related-auto-configuration-in-spring-boot)